# How do I and other facebook users embed my simple google gadget on their wall / tab

Tags: facebook, google-gadget

I have a simple Google Gadget that shows products from a Zazzle Storekeeper's store. I'd like to make this available to those storekeepers on their own facebook wall / tab. Is this possible? It doesn't need access to any of their Facebook info other.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook Page Apps are at their core just simple iFrames which can load any other URL on the internet into them. Read more about [Apps on Facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/) and ensure that what you're doing complies with [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) and it should all be pretty straightforward.